# How to list commiters sorted by number of commits (commit count)?

Tags: mercurial

In mercurial, how do you list commiters sorted by number of commits (commit count).

Using git, you can do something like this :

```
git shortlog -ns
```

What is the equivalent command for mercurial ?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There is no pure Mercurial solution, but you can do something like:

`hg log --template "{author|person}\n" | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr`

If you want to be able to type `hg shortlog`, you can add the following to your `.hgrc` or `mercurial.ini`:

```
[alias]
shortlog = !hg log --template "{author|person}\n" | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Answer (score 44):

The [churn extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ChurnExtension) can draw you a nice histogram with the information. Add

```
[extensions]
churn =
```

to your Mercurial configuration file and run

```
$ hg churn -c
```

to get a histogram like this:

```
mpm@selenic.com                           3234 *************************    
thomas@intevation.de                       974 ********
pmezard@gmail.com                          939 *******
```

That historgram is from the Mercurial repository itself.

Comment: http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#extensions , The Mercurial Config file is on Linux ~/.hgrc , the churn extension is distributed with mercurial.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a [script for Roundup](http://sourceforge.net/p/roundup/code/ci/default/tree/scripts/contributors.py) to build list of project contributors by years based on Mercurial history. It is cross-platform, public domain and should be easy to customize for your own purpose.